# Why does this print out the answer twice?

Tags: java

I wrote a simple calculator, but it prints the answer twice. So if I write 7 + 2 and then select (1) (addition) it prints out 7 twice.

```
import java.util.Scanner;
public class first {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        int num1;
        int num2;
        Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in);
        System.out.println("Enter first number and second number:");
        num1 = input.nextInt();
        num2 = input.nextInt();
        int ans;
        System.out.println("Enter your selection: 1 for addition, 2 for subtraction, 3 for multiplication and 4 for division:");
        int choose;
        choose = input.nextInt();
        switch (choose){
            case 1:
                System.out.println(num1 + num2);
                break;

            case 2:
                System.out.println(num1 - num2);
                break;

            case 3:
                System.out.println(num1 * num2);
                break;

            case 4:
                System.out.println(num1 / num2);
                break;
        }


        System.out.println(num1 + num2);

    }
}
```

This is what I get if I do 2 + 5: 7
7

Comment: Because you're printing once inside every case and once again at the end ?

Comment: Don't print after the switch!

Comment: Thanks guys, I am new to this.

Comment: Dear Stamp it is okay that you are new to these kind of problems but I suggest you using debugger, break points and step over/in capabilities of your IDE seeing what exactly is happening at each line of your code. without debugging it is very hard to find bugs, problems and glitches specially in complex algorithms and programs. so watch youtube or read tutorials to learn how to use debugger.

Comment: good question :)

Answer (score 3):

You have a print statement in the switch-case statement, then again after the switch-case. Two print statements, two outputs.

Remove the one after your switch-case and it should work fine

Comment: Wow, why didn't I think of that. Thanks for letting me know!